# Optimising CoreData fulltext query

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, full-text-search, nspredicate

I have a large collection of CoreData objects which represent files. Periodically, I need to search this collection and find files which exist at a given path. Currently, I'm constructing the following NSPredicate and performing a fairly basic executeFetchRequest to find all results which match my query.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"path ==[c] %@", receivedPath];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Files" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setFetchBatchSize:10];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];
```

The issue I'm having is that this function is called fairly frequently and the executeFetchRequest is accounting for a significant percentage of execution time (Instruments tells me the function accounts for around 49.2% in total, with 98.1% of that total spent on the executeFetchRequest call). I'm using `NSSQLiteStoreType` for my persistent store and have the `path` attribute indexed in my MOM.

My question is, how can I optimise this? I've considered setting up a lowercasePath attribute, and ditching the [c] modifier on the comparison, but am unsure as to what impact (if any) that would have on execution time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mac or iOS? On Mac, [Search Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SearchKit/Reference/reference.html) is probably a better fit for doing fulltext search.

Comment: I apologise for not mentioning. This is on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `[c]` should make a difference. `==[c]` is probably translated to an SQLite `LIKE` operator for which SQLite cannot use indexes, if I remember correctly. Speaking of which, do you have the attribute marked as indexed in your model? If not, you should do so, but again, with a case-insensitive search, this probably doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This gives me a little hope. Having enabled the -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug argument, I'm unable to see any LIKE queries being performed. It appears that all full-text comparisons are carried out by a NSCoreDataStringCompare function, which I'm unable to find documentation on.

Comment: It probably does something similar to `LIKE`, it's possible to configure SQLite to use custom functions in queries. Do you see the same when you use a plain `==`?

Comment: Nope! Looks as though removing the [c] modifier results in a simple path = ? query. I'll give it a try and mark your answer correct if it resolves the issue!